# Who know how to implement the 2D bone animation showed in the game?

Tags: physics, skeletal-animation

I wonder how do they implement the bone animation in the flash game http://www.foddy.net/athletics.swf Do you know any study materials which I can start to learn 2D bone system from? I just implemented a avatar system by compose multiple bitmaps in each frame(similar with maple story), but some guys tell me that, a bone system can save more art resources, so I want to learn some thing about that.

Comment: Just a suggestion: change "some gays" to "some guys" :)

Comment: A serious typing error, fixed :o)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the bones/joints in QWOP (the game you're referring to) are modeled using the [Flash Port of Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/). By pressing the buttons you apply forces to these joints and make the character move *eventually*.

On the Box2D page you'll also find ragdoll examples that might serve as a starting-point for your characters. You should be aware that creating animations using such a setup (eg. using a physics-engine and apply forces to joints) can be *very* complicated and might not yield the desired results.

If you just need a "skinnable" avatar, it would probably be simpler to use pre-animated characters. You can use the [bones-system of Flash](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/flash/articles/lrvid4058_fl.html) for this and replace the different MovieClips (eg. upper leg, lower leg etc.) at runtime to get some sort of skinning.

**Update:** I created a [very basic example](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1293526425) how you could easily change the appearance of an animated character (click to change skin, sorry for crappy art). Source file is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/iktest). Different skins are on different frames. You could most likely extend this concept to dynamically load new skins though.

Comment: Could you please re-up this file? The link is dead.

Comment: @bottleboot Example is [here](http://megaswf.com/file/2508766), source is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/iktest). It's nothing spectacular though.. just changing the frames of each skin-component (eg. lower-arm, hand, etc.) using ActionScript.